# Create new variable to store each result during While loop

Tags: php, variables, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that loops through 3 results and echo's these out in a list. It will **always** be 3 results.

**Here is my current PHP:**

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
{

    echo "<li>".$row['SessionValue']."</li>";
    // prefer to store each value in its own variable

}
```

**However I'd like to store the `$row['SessionValue']` value in each loop in a new variable.**

So....

*first loop:* `$i0 = $row['SessionValue'];`

*second loop:* `$i1 = $row['SessionValue'];`

*third loop:* `$i2 = $row['SessionValue'];`

**How would I achieve this with PHP?**

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: put it in an array.. btw, tell us what you're *really* trying to do (not *how* you're trying to do it)

Comment: Thanks Karoly. Sorry, that's a good point. I'll try to approach it in that way next time. Can you explain how I would do this using an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lst_count = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
  $lst_count[] = $row["SessionValue"];
```

Comment: You're welcome... (Karoly already suggested this before I finished my answer).

Comment: Strictly speaking, Niko's answer - which creates 3 separate variables - is what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need another variable that gets incremented:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
{
    ${i.$count++} = $row['SessionValue'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Niko. I'm afraid this gives me no variables in the loop.

Comment: Put `var_dump($i0);` after the loop, it will output the first value!

Comment: Thank you, Niko. Will try just now.

Comment: Though I would recommend using the solution with an array, that will turn out to be easier to handle.

Comment: Your answer certainly answered my question, but you guys are right, there was a better way to do it. Thanks for your time and effort here sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this have SUM of all value:

```
$total = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
{
   $total[] = $row["SessionValue"]
}  $sumAll = array_sum($total);
```